# Is it possible to use a mongorc.js in MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'd like to use my custom commands defined in a *[mongorc.js](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#mongorc-js-file)* in MongoDB Compass. Is this possible? 
Is it possible to use a *mongorc.js* in MongoDB Compass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compass does not support the `mongo` shell's notion of a `mongorc.js` startup file. The `mongo` shell is a lower level JavaScript console environment that provides some basic scripting capabilities for administrators; Compass is a desktop application which does not allow arbitrary execution of user-provided JavaScript.

However, if you want to customise Compass it is possible to [Create Compass Plugins](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/plugins/creating-compass-plugins/) which are implemented as ReactJS modules. Compass plugins extend predefined [roles in the Compass UI](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/plugins/reference/#plugin-roles) (such as the global header, database-level tabs, or collection-level tabs) and run in a much more [limited security context](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/plugins/creating-compass-plugins/#restrictions) as compared to the `mongo` shell.

Implementing a plugin is definitely more involved than a simple JavaScript include, but there are interesting possibilities if you want to tweak your admin UI (and perhaps share plugins with others).

For more information see: [Plugin Tutorials](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/plugins/plugin-tutorials/) and [Compass Plugin Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/plugins/reference/).